# How do I use MicropostsHelper to wrap posts when they are feed.items? Hartl Ruby On Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

Following the instructions in Hartl's RoR Tutorial Listing 10.47 I made a `MicropostsHelper` file to wrap `Microposts` with very long words.

It works just fine on the user page where `Microposts` are called with

```
<%= wrap(micropost.content) %>
```

But when I try to invoke it on the front page where `Microposts` are called with

```
<%= wrap(feed_item.content) %>
```

it does not work.

I thought perhaps I needed to make an identicle `feed_itemHelper` but that didn't work at all. I assume what I need to do is let the `feed_item.content` know that it can use the helper but I can't see how to do that.

```
Microposts Helper

module MicropostsHelper

  def wrap(content)
    sanitize(raw(content.split.map{ |s| wrap_long_string(s) }.join(' ')))
  end

  private

    def wrap_long_string(text, max_width = 30)
      zero_width_space = "&#8203;"
      regex = /.{1,#{max_width}}/
      (text.length < max_width) ? text :
                                  text.scan(regex).join(zero_width_space)
    end
end
```

**UPDATE**

It appears now that the WRAP is working but the long words are still forcing the Posted `<%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.feed` to left align. Here is an image of a wrapped post, misaligned, above a properly aligned non wrapped post.

OK, can't post images yet... Here it is on flickr
[Flickr image](http://www.flickr.com/photos/beez/9821399175/)

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: try add the following line after class FeedItemController < ApplicationHelper : `include MicropostsHelper`

Comment: Where should I add that? I don't have a FeedItemController. I tried adding include MicropostsHelper to the application_controller but that didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the gravatar css class is using a `float: left`, I think you are just seeing the text wrapping around the gravatar image.  Depending on the size of your gravatar image it will take 2 or 3 lines of content text to push it down past the image.  I set the wrap_long_string method's default to `max_width = 60` to help take up a little more space to the right before it wraps.  Look in app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss around line 208 or so for where the float is defined for the gravatar css class.  To keep all the text to stay right of the image would likely involve some additional css.

```
.gravatar {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I think you're right. Thanks for answering such an old question. I can't benefit from raising the max width because I've cramped it into a smaller space but it's good to know that if I can give it a bit more space somehow it will take advantage of it. Thank you for seeing the wood for the trees.